# setSinkId change muliple audio ouputs

Tags: webrtc, web-audio-api

Here is the problem,

First I enumerate all the devices that I have available with in select elements:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
```

When I change one output, it sounds in the device that I choose.

```
HTMLMediaElement.setSinkId(deviceId)
```

After if I play another audio and change the device output (setSinkId), it changes also the first one to the last deviceId. So I have both sounds in the same device.

Do I need to have the last adapter.js version to implement properly that problem?

********* EDITED **********

Following the above comment, it try the web audio, but not success. With getUserMedia everything is fine.

```
navigator.getUserMedia( { audio: true, video: false },
    function (mediaStream) {
        // Create an audio context for the audio
        var ac = new (window.AudioContext || window.webKitAudioContext)();
        // Create a clone of the stream, if not the id of all the stream is default
        //var streamClone = stream.clone();
        var ss = ac.createMediaStreamSource(mediaStream);
        // Create a destination
        var sd = ac.createMediaStreamDestination()
        ss.connect(sd);
        element.srcObject = sd.stream;
        // Play the sound
        element.play();
        element.setSinkId(deviceId).then(function() {
            console.log('Set deviceId('+deviceId+') in the selected audio element');
        });
    },
    function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
);
```

But using my remote stream, I cannot get any noise

```
var ac = new (window.AudioContext || window.webKitAudioContext)();
// Create a clone of the stream, if not the id of all the stream is default
var streamClone = stream.clone();
var ss = ac.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
// Create a destination
var sd = ac.createMediaStreamDestination()
ss.connect(sd);
// Element is my HTMLMediaElement
element.srcObject = sd.stream;
// Play the sound
element.play();
element.setSinkId(deviceId).then(function() {
   console.log('Set deviceId('+deviceId+') in the selected audio element');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is most likely caused by how Chrome renders audio. See [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/discuss-webrtc/vrw44ZGE0gs/2YJ6yUEjBgAJ) for a description which also suggests using webaudio to workaround the problem.

adapter.js can not fix this.