# Change sink id of audio track of video element using setSinkId api

Tags: javascript, webrtc, html5-video, web-audio-api

I am trying to change audio(only) output device of a video element but can't set the sink id for the audio.

It worked with audio element but while setting sink id on video element didn't work directly therefore I tried by getting `audioTracks` from video's `srcObject` stream

```
const stream=videoElement.srcObject;
stream.getAudioTracks().forEach(track=>{
  track.setSinkId(deviceId);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setSinkId is a method of the HTML audio/video element (HTMLMediaElement.prototype.setSinkId exists; not that this is not yet supported in all browsers so you might want to make the call depend on this), not a method of the MediaStreamTrack.

See [the canonical sample](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/) for details

Comment: After calling `setSinkId` on a specific media element every other media element also started to use the same device for output. Is it default behavior?

Comment: found your another answer on the issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/48329464/1642219